# Browser tearing when scrolling

Tags: nvidia, graphics, firefox, google-chrome, video

Hi I recently installed Xubuntu 16.04 and am having problems getting browsers to work. I tried using firefox but there was flickering/tearing in horizontal bands across the screen and none of the solutions (turning off hardware acceleration, restarting in safe mode).

I tried installing chrome but it caused a problem where whenever I tried dragging any windows across the screen they would stutter and lag. I fixed this by disabling hardware acceleration but now I have the same problem I did with firefox. I tried enabling GPU rasterization in chrome://flags but that does not work.

I am using nvidia driver v384 w/ compton and have a GTX 1060 installed.

Comment: Are You sure You are using nvidia drivers ? What is the output of this command `inxi Gx` (install inxi if You don't have it - `sudo apt install inxi`). This will print the currently used graphics driver.